# Rails 4 - how to compare two collection of objects and pick the same ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord, hash

I am running 2 (sometimes 3) searches, like:

```
first_search  = Company.where('...') # returns 2 objects
second_search = Company.where('...') # returns 4 objects
```

Let's say that `first_search` contains objects with these IDs:

```
10
20
```

`second_search` contains

```
10
30
40
50
```

I would like to save to another variable (say `results`) objects with the same IDs from `first_search` and `second_search`, thus `results` would only contain the object with ID:

```
10
```

How to do this?

Thank you/

**EDIT:**
the intersection is working based on the `id` column, right? Would be there a way to make the intersection work on a different column? Say `name`?

Comment: is it an array of ids?

Comment: It's array of objects

Comment: @user984621 You can do this `Intersection` operation from DB level. I think.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this works on objects as well.

```
results = first_search & second_search
```

Comment: Thank you @Nithin for the answer - this intersection works based on the `id` column, right? Would be there a way to make the intersection work on a  different column? Say `name`? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are just trying to take intersection, you can do

```
results = first_search & second_search
```

but as you want to find intersection of objects, here is the link that already answers it. I hope it helps you.

[Intersection of two relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435389/intersection-of-two-relations)